# Adding data to the MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, insertion-sort

I have a table of the structure of the following type. The url data seems to be fine. The bay values (B1 B2 B3) are set to 1 of integer kind.

```
  DateToBook          | B1 | B2 | B3 | 
 ------------------------------------
  8March2013         | 1  |  1 |  1 |
```

I couldn't get the values inserted. The baycount for the above structure is 3.

```
   <?php
   $DB_hostname = "localhost";
   $DB_Name = "root";
   $DB_pass = "pass123";

   if(isset($_GET["tabName"])){
       $tableName = $_GET["tabName"];
       $dB = $_GET["db"];
       $bayCount = $_GET["bayNo"];
       $date =  $_GET["d"];
       $b = '1';
    }

   $con = mysql_connect($DB_Hostname,$DB_Name,$DB_pass) or die(mysql_error());


   mysql_select_db($db, $con);

   $_bayColumn = array();
   for ($i = 1; $i <= $bayCount; $i++) {
      $_bayColumn[] = "B$i";
   }
   echo $_bayColumn[0];


   mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (DateToBook) VALUES ($date)");


   for ($j =0; $j < $bayCount; $j++) {

   mysql_query("UPDATE $tableName SET $_bayColumn[$j] = '$b'  WHERE DateToBook = '$date'");


   }




  mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

Is there anything that is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: i think you must replace this line`   for ($j =0; $j <= $bayCount; $j++) {`

Comment: Cant equalise to baycount because Im looping into the index of the $_bayColumn[] array

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `$b` only exists in the `if` statement below. If `$b` is always 1, why don't you just write `1` in your query instead of `$b`

Or change it to the following:

```
$b = '1'; //Place it here
if(isset($_GET["tabName"])){
   $tableName = $_GET["tabName"];
   $dB = $_GET["db"];
   $bayCount = $_GET["bayNo"];
   $date =  $_GET["d"];
   $b = '1'; //You can get rid of this now
}
```

Furthermore, I fully agree with the comments above and you SHOULD use MySQLI or PDO

Comment: baycount is of type integer. "B1 INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1" Is is something to do with that?

Comment: Yes true! even without the for loop I couldn't insert the date.
DateToBook is a primary key and of type Varchar(11)

Comment: `mysql_query("INSERT INTO $tableName (DateToBook) VALUES ($date)");` What query is generated? (`var_dump("INSERT INTO $tableName (DateToBook) VALUES ($date)");`)

Comment: The query seems to work when I try on Php MyAdmin sql query page.

Comment: Yeah but in phpMyAdmin PHP does not generate your query. Try placing all of your values in 'quotes', tablenames in those things above your tab `\`key\``. -> actually, rewrite it in PDO or MySQLi

Answer (score 0):

You can use `die("INSERT INTO $tableName (DateToBook) VALUES ($date)")` to check if u got the right value.